# ss slower than netstat

Tags: netstat, ss

The man page for netstat says :

> NOTE 
>   This program is obsolete. Replacement for netstat is ss. Replacement for netstat -r is ip route. Replacement for 
>   netstat -i is ip -s link. Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr." 
>   ​​

When netstat and ss are run with options t (for TCP sockets) and n (to avoid dns lookups), ss is faster than netstat :

```
time netstat -tn 
. 
. 
real 0m0.052s 
user 0m0.005s 
sys 0m0.037s 
time ss -tn 
. 
. 
real 0m0.018s 
user 0m0.002s 
sys 0m0.013s
```

However, when used with an additional option p, somehow, ss is very much slower than netstat:

```
time netstat -tnp 
. 
. 
real 0m0.072s 
user 0m0.010s 
sys 0m0.056s 
time ss -tnp 
. 
. 
real 0m3.913s 
user 0m0.585s 
sys 0m3.288s
```

There is another command - lsof - which is faster than ss but still slower than netstat :

```
time lsof -i TCP 
. 
. 
real 0m0.126s 
user 0m0.050s 
sys 0m0.057s
```

So, is netstat the best command to get tcp network details and with PID of the process to which the tcp socket belongs?